# Phaser State Manager onUpdateCallback not firing

Tags: phaser-framework

I would like to hook into the phaser.js main update loop. I have a parent class that initiates my phaser game + inclused a few helper functions. I need this class to listen to the main update loop. I can do a sentInterval, but i would rather hook into phaserjs's loop.

Since i am working with States... I figured i could set "onUpdateCallback" on the SateManager. So on the parent/helper class that initiates my phaser game...

```
    this.state_boot = new StateBoot();
    this.state_main = new StateMain();

    this.state_manager = this.game.state;
    this.state_manager.add(this.state_boot.getKey(), this.state_boot);
    this.state_manager.add(this.state_main.getKey(), this.state_main);

    this.state_manager.onUpdateCallback = function(){
        console.log('got hereeee')
    };
```

Did i miss something here? my anon function is never triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your full initialisation code? You don't actually start any state here, maybe you forgot to add something like this at the end of it?

```
this.state_manager.start(this.state_boot.getKey());
// Personally I prefer just using the namestring
//this.state_manager.start('BootState');
```

Comment: no i have further code below, where i actually start/switch states. I have a method that handles smooth transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I decided that this approach could an anti-pattern and a possible headache to follow. My new approach is to utilize Phaser timers, and have the corresponding class maintain the timer instance